# Issue when packaging a solution

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, sharepoint-framework, spfx-tooling

[image]

When I am packaging a solution I am facing this error when I run the command `gulp bundle -ship`.

Answer (score 1):

You need two dashes, not one. The command is `gulp bundle --ship`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below sequence of commands for packaging SPFx solution:

```
gulp clean
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

Follow below documentations for more information:

1. [Deploy your client-side web part to a SharePoint page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page)
2. [Build And Deploy The Client Side Web Part (SPFx) In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/build-and-deploy-the-client-side-web-part-spfx-in-sharepoint-online/)